# Setting ScalaTest Selenium maxInstances for browser

Tags: maven, selenium, scalatest

We have a maven plugin that runs selenium with scala.  The arguments passed are formatted as such:

```
<argLine>-Dbrowser=chrome -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=${project.basedir}/browser/drivers/chrome/2.25/mac64/chromedriver</argLine>
```

I've tried adding

> -DmaxInstances=5

, as well as using

> -browser="browserName=chrome,maxInstances=5,chromeDriver=theDriver"

however they have returned errors.

Does anyone know the correct command line argument using the -D... format?

Answer (score 1):

An example execution would be:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=theDriver -jar selenium-standalone-server-3.0.1.jar ${SE_OPTS}
```

where `${SE_OPTS}` are the options that selenium takes.  the options depend on which role you are running.

- [Options for Standalone](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/internal/utils/configuration/StandaloneConfiguration.java#L31)
- [Options for Hub](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/internal/utils/configuration/GridHubConfiguration.java#L39)
- [Options for Nodes](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/internal/utils/configuration/GridNodeConfiguration.java#L49)

*(see the `@Parameter`'s)*

Since version 3.0, we are using JCommander, so ensure that your `-D...` options are specified **before** `-jar`

Comment: Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place, however there is no parameter for setting the max instances of chrome that can be opened simultaneously in the parameters.

Comment: I think the answer may actually lie in the ScalaTest + Selenium.  It seems to launch stand alone instances of chrome, i.e. it might not be using grid.